# Ajax Run external page, reload current page

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, page-refresh

I'm reading data from a database and then using a button to selectively delete entries.

I'm using the following code on a button click and it works exactly as I need.

```
$(".delete").click( function() {
    if (confirm('Delete This  ?')) {
        $.ajax({ url : 'doMode.php?mode=delete=' + $(this).attr('data') });
    }
    return false;
});
```

The entry is deleted and if I manually refresh the current page ( the page the delete button is on ) then that entry has been removed.

What I would like is to have the 'delete' button click delete the entry and the refresh the current page. I've tried this and it didn't work, it didn't even delete the entry.

```
$(".delete").click( function() {
    if (confirm('Delete This  ?')) {
        $.ajax({ url : 'doMode.php?mode=delete=' + $(this).attr('data') });
        window.location.reload();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Can someone advise where I'm going wrong.

**UPDATE**

For clarity. When I've completed the delete I want the original page to reload. Thats the page with the data and buttons on, not the doMode.php page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call it in a `success callback` of your ajax function

[From Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/)

**success (Local Event)**

> This event is only called if the request was
>   successful (no errors from the server, no errors with the data).

```
$(".delete").click( function() {
 if (confirm('Delete This  ?')) {

  $.ajax({
   url:"doMode.php?mode=delete=" + $(this).attr('data'),
   success: function(){
    window.location.reload();
   }
  });//ajax end

 }
 return false;
});// click end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That generates an error.
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`  Where : is after success.  Any idea how to resolve that ?

Comment: Thanks the amended page doesn't error now, but it still doesn't reload. I'm wondering if this is because I want to reload the original page, the one with the button on it.. not the page loaded via ajax.

Comment: I've added a setTimeout function within the success and now it works.
I think it was working but refreshing quicker than the delete was happening. I've marked your post as the solution as it pointed me in the right direction.  This is what I've added to the success function.

`setTimeout(function(){
               window.location = "?mode=done";
             }, 100);`